# Do I really need OWL reasoning?

Tags: sparql, rdf, owl, graphdb

I recently asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46891382/can-graphdb-load-10-million-statements-with-owl-reasoning) about the feasibility of loading about 10 million statements into a triplestore with OWL reasoning enabled.

That has lead to some StackOverflow comments as well as discussion within my research group about whether or not we really need OWL reasoning.

---

#### I'll start with a real-world query that doesn't seem to *require* OWL reasoning.

"41167-4120-0" is the NDC Code that identifies the [commercial drug product "Fexofenadine hydrochloride 180 MG Oral Tablet [Allegra]" in the US](https://dailymed.nlm.nih.gov/dailymed/drugInfo.cfm?setid=81c1dcbb-28b3-4ad5-9f3d-9ccc16ddd173).

A slightly modified version of the NDC appears as a label in the drug ontology (specifically file *dron-ndc.owl*):

```
http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/DRON_00604430 rdfs:label "41167412000"
```

DrON makes the following OWL assertions:

```
http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/DRON_00604430 is a packaged drug product 
    and is rdfs:subClass of 
    ( has_proper_part some http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/DRON_00083688 )

http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/DRON_00083688 
    rdfs:subClassOf http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/DRON_00062350

http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/DRON_00062350 has_proper_part some 
    (scattered molecular aggregate  
    and (is bearer of some active ingredient) 
    and (is bearer of some (mass and 
    (has measurement unit label value milligram) 
    and (has specified value <value> ))) 
    and (has granular part some fexofenadine))
```

And ChEBI says:

```
http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/CHEBI_5050 rdfs:label "fexofenadine"
    subClassOf (has role some anti-allergic agent)
```

and

```
http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/CHEBI_50857 rdfs:label "anti-allergic agent"
```

So in order to link a NDC code and a therapeutic role, I can write a query like the following

```
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX obo: <http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/>
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
select distinct 
?ndcval ?packdrugprod ?drugbrand ?brandlab ?drugform  ?api ?apilab ?drugrole
where {
    values ?ndcval {
        "41167412000" 
    }
    ?packdrugprod rdfs:subClassOf ?hasproppart ;
                  rdfs:label ?ndcval .
    ?hasproppart a owl:Restriction ;
                 owl:onProperty <http://www.obofoundry.org/ro/ro.owl#has_proper_part> ;
                 owl:someValuesFrom ?drugbrand .
    ?drugbrand rdfs:subClassOf ?drugform ;
               rdfs:label ?brandlab .
    ?drugform rdfs:subClassOf ?proppart .
    ?proppart a owl:Restriction ;
              owl:onProperty <http://www.obofoundry.org/ro/ro.owl#has_proper_part> ;
              owl:someValuesFrom ?valSource1 .
    ?valSource1 owl:intersectionOf ?intsect1 .
    # scat mol agg
    ?intsect1 rdf:first obo:OBI_0000576 .
    ?intsect1 rdf:rest ?scatmolag .
    ?scatmolag rdf:first ?bearacting .
    ?scatmolag rdf:rest ?intsect3 .
    # bearer of active ingredient
    ?bearacting a owl:Restriction ;
                owl:onProperty obo:BFO_0000053 ;
                owl:someValuesFrom obo:DRON_00000028 .
    ?intsect3 rdf:first ?granpart .
    ?intsect3 rdf:rest ?r .
    # has granular part fexofenadine
    ?granpart a owl:Restriction ;
              owl:onProperty obo:BFO_0000071 ;
              owl:someValuesFrom ?api .
    ?api rdfs:subClassOf ?rolerestr ;
         rdfs:label ?apilab .
    # has anti allergic role
    ?rolerestr a owl:Restriction ;
               owl:onProperty obo:RO_0000087 ;
               owl:someValuesFrom ?drugrole  .
    ?drugrole rdfs:label ?drlab .
    values ?drugrole {
        obo:CHEBI_50857 
    }
}
```

---

### Concerns:

#### What about accessing nested subClass relationships without reasoning?

The example above was easy because fexofenadine is directly asserted to have the "anti-allergic" role

What if I am interested in people taking nitrate esters?  Nitroglycerin is a nitroglycerol, which is in turn a nitrate ester.  If I used a repository with no reasoning enabled, I would have to explicitly use a ***property path*** to find patients who are taking any nitrate esters, with a snippet like this (right?)

```
?s rdfs:subClassOf* <http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/CHEBI_51080> .
```

#### What about inferring the classes to which individuals belong to?

What if my ontology says something like

```
:ViagraPill owl:equivalentClass ( :pill 
    and (:hasColor some :blue ) 
    and (:hasShape some :diamond))
:steelBlue rdfs:subClassOf :blue
```

And I have data triples that say something like

```
:patient1 :consumed :pill1 .
:pill1 :hasColor :steelBlue1 ;
    :hasShape :diamond1 .
:steelBlue1 a :steelBlue .
:diamond1 a :diamond.
```

And I want to write a query for patients who have consumed Viagra pills:

```
?patient a :patient ;
    :consumed ?pill .
?pill a :ViagraPill .
```

***I would need some form of OWL reasoning for that, right?***

Comment: I assume that `:ViagraPill` is a class, right? Then the axiom should be `:ViagraPill rdfs:subClassOf ...` But even then, it wouldn't be enough. To infer that `:pill1` is an instance of class `:ViagraPill` it would need for an equivalence axiom, i.e. `:ViagraPill owl:equivalentClass ...` This is necessary because you want to infer "from right to left".

Comment: But to give you an answer to your question *"I would need some form of OWL reasoning for that, right?"* -> Yes, it would need some kind of OWL reasoning. OWL Horst, OWL RL, something like that. Sure, it depends on other axioms that should be considered.

Comment: Ah, just forgot: `:steelBlue1 a :blue` and `:diamond1 a :diamond` is missing in the data triples.

Answer (score 2):

I always thought the tendency of OBO and other bio, life science and agri ontologies to use millions of classes but very few individuals is a mistake.

The above modeling means that for every instance of Allegra (every single pill, a box or other package) you need to infer statements like "it's a scattered molecular aggregate" and "is bearer of some active ingredient" and "has granular part some fexofenadine". I find this wasteful.

It's better to have those statements attached directly to the drug definition: as simple statements, not as Restrictions. You can do that in two ways:

1. Still treat Allegra as a class, but attach the props directly to it by using punning
2. Treat Allegra as an instance, and if you ever need to describe individual pills, use statement like `pill dct:type Allegra`

Then you can access the pill properties simply through its drug (class or not class):

```
?pill rdf:type ?drug. # or in Variant2: dct:type
?drug obo:RO_0000087 obo:CHEBI_50857. # has anti allergic role
```

It'll be similar to your query but quite simpler and faster because it'll avoid Restrictions.

(As for the need to parse `rdf:Lists`, that must be a heavy burden on the consciousnesses of ontology creators):

```
    ?intsect1 rdf:first obo:OBI_0000576 .
    ?intsect1 rdf:rest ?scatmolag .
    ?scatmolag rdf:first ?bearacting .
    ?scatmolag rdf:rest ?intsect3 .
    # bearer of active ingredient
```

Here's your Viagram example in simplified form. I've turned the nomenclature values `:blue` and `:diamond` into individuals (`skos:Concept`) because I see no reason for them to be classes (`:steelBlue1` makes no sense to me).

```
:ViagraPill a DrugForm;
  :hasColor :blue;
  :hasShape :diamond.
:steelBlue a skos:Concept;
  skos:broader :blue.

:patient1 :consumed :pill1.
:pill1 :hasColor :steelBlue; :hasShape :diamond.
```

The color and shape is a necessary but not sufficient condition for identifying the drug, so `?drugForm` below is a **possible** drug of that pill but not certain:

```
select ?patient ?drugForm {
  ?patient a :patient; :consumed ?pill.
  ?pill :hasColor ?color; :hasShape ?shape.
  ?drugForm :hasColor ?color1; :hasShape ?shape.
  ?color skos:broaderTransitive? ?color1
}
```

Here I've used transitive reasoning: the path `skos:broaderTransitive?` is faster than the path `skos:broader*`.

Reasoning is not an all-or-nothing affair: you can pick and choose rules that you need from the builtin rulesets. Eg if you include RDFS reasoning then you can simplify:

```
?x a ?s. ?s rdfs:subClassOf* :CHEBI_51080
```

to just

```
?x a :CHEBI_51080
```

The default builtin ruleset RDFS-Plus-optimized includes RDFS, inverses and transitive.
See http://graphdb.ontotext.com/documentation/enterprise/rules-optimisations.html for more advice.

You may object: "Didn't you say you'll attach props directly to drug (classes)? How come you also attach them to `:pill1` above?".

I think that's fine: we could declare those props to have domain `:DrugIndividual or :DrugForm or :Drug`, and interpret them as "observed" for `:DrugIndividual` but "nominal" or "required" for `:DrugForm and :Drug`.
BTW, I like to declare polymorphic domains using `schema:domainIncludes ...` instead of `rdfs:range [a owl:Class; owl:unionOf (...)]`.

If you don't want to attach props to drug individuals (instances) then you'd have to use an "unknown class" for the pill, eg like this:

```
:patient1 :consumed :pill1.
:pill1 a [:hasColor :steelBlue; :hasShape :diamond].
```

With the respective slight complication in querying:

```
select ?patient ?drugForm {
  ?patient a :patient; :consumed ?pill.
  ?pill a [:hasColor ?color; :hasShape ?shape].
  ?drugForm :hasColor ?color1; :hasShape ?shape.
  ?color skos:broaderTransitive? ?color1
}
```

To summarize:

- GraphDB does not support OWL DL, it supports QL and RL.
- OBO-style ontologies use millions of classes, which prescribes the inference of a whole bunch of props from class Restrictions to individuals; which I find wasteful.