# GraphDB Free 8.5 re-inferring uses a single core?

Tags: sparql, rdf, ontology, graphdb

I am trying to load several large biomedical ontologies into a GraphDB Owl Horst optimized repository, along with 10s of millions of triples using terms from those ontologies.  I can load these data into a RDFS+ optimized repo in less than 1 hour, but I can't even load one of the ontologies ([chebi_lite](ftp://ftp.ebi.ac.uk/pub/databases/chebi/ontology/)) if I let it go overnight.  That's using [loadrdf](http://graphdb.ontotext.com/free/loading-data-using-the-loadrdf-tool.html) on a 64 core, 256 GB AWS server.

My earlier question [Can GraphDB load 10 million statements with OWL reasoning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46891382/can-graphdb-load-10-million-statements-with-owl-reasoning) lead to the suggestion that I use the `preload` command, followed by re-inferring.  The preload indeed went very quickly, but when it comes to re-inferring, only one core is used.  I haven't been able to let it go for more than an hour yet.  **Is re-inferring using just one core a consequence of using the free version?  Might `loadrdf` work better if I just did a better configuration?**

When I use `loadrdf`, all cores go close to 100%, but the memory usage never goes over 10% or so.  I have tinkered with the JVM memory settings a little, but I don't really know what I'm doing.  For example

```
-Xmx80g -Dpool.buffer.size=2000000
```